# Could this site change its title to retro and micro computing?

Tags: discussion, scope

I noticed that KaiOS devices being third in usage and quite popular in India have very limited support.

Would this site consider becoming more general to micro computing or potentially at minimum adding a Kaios tag?

Comment: Well, the address would be awfully long: retrocomputing-microcomputing.stackexchange.com.

Comment: I was thinking retro-microcomputing but anyways the moderators said no so I think the likelihood is slim.

Comment: If it doesn't require a raised-floor air-conditioned room, it's not a computer I'm interested in from the point of view of "retrocomputing" :-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Nope.

KaiOS is a proprietary fork of Firefox OS, which is fairly modern; certainly more modern than what's currently on-topic. KaiOS is on-topic on other sites (I believe [Super User](https://superuser.com/)), but it's *not* a Retrocomputing platform. If we make microcomputing on-topic, then basically *everything* is on-topic.

Comment: I tried and the question was shut down.  https://superuser.com/questions/1657965/kaios-doesn-t-sync-gmail-contacts

Comment: @William Hmm. That's a shame; we don't have a site for KaiOS questions. But this is _definitely_ not the right one to try to make include it! Have you tried a KaiOS forum?

Comment: Reddit is the best I have found so far.

Comment: @William You could try proposing a site on [area51.se], but I don't think that has much of a chance.

Answer (score 9):

I don’t think so. As much as I usually support broadening the site’s scope somewhat, I think this would be too much of a stretch.

For the kinds of devices this site usually focuses on, they tend to be relatively simple, target power users/‘prosumers’ and have an architecture that, if not fully open, then is at least common knowledge and ‘easy to keep in your head’ to one extent or another. Just a little knowledge of assembly language and electronics can get you quite far with those devices.

From afar, KaiOS looks like a very different kind of platform: though based on the open-source Linux and Firefox, it is considerably more opaque and high-level (being based on Web technologies), with many more moving parts.  It’s much more like Android than the Commodore 64.

I think it would take a very different kind of audience with different skills and mindset to answer questions in this area, and it would not much overlap with the site’s audience of today.

Comment: We accept questions about retro-micro-computers and their software. We don't accept questions about computers and software that are not retro-, regardless of whether they are micro- or otherwise.